# NPN BJT on voltage

Tags: transistors, bjt, npn

I'm in the process of designing this small circuit using an SS8050 NPN transistor.

I have an input base voltage of 1.28V and I'd like it to be working as a switch to turn on a little buzzer.

According to the datasheet, the base-emitter on voltage is 0,7 V ish when the collector current is 30 mA, so I picked a 4000 ohm base-resistance to get the right voltage drop.

Unfortunately, I think the circuit doesn't work well and I hope you help me to sort it right.

Can you help me to check the calculations? Is the base-emitter-on voltage the voltage I must apply to turn on the transistor and allow that Ic current? What's the meaning of VCe=1V on the diagram I mentioned before?

- I2= I1/hfe=  30  10-3/200=0,15 mA
- ΔV= 1,28 V -0,68V=0,6 V
- ΔV= R2*I2 ---> R2=4000 Ω

[Datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/SS8050-117753.pdf)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You've drawn the transistor upside down, with the emitter labelled "C". How is it actually connected?

Comment: To use it as a switch, drive the base with more current. A 1:10 ratio is often used, so use 3 mA, not 0.15.

Comment: You've drawn a PNP transistor, but the SS8050 is an NPN transistor.

Comment: Your schematic wrongly shows a PNP transistor with its E and C terminals and voltages like it is an NPN transistor. An NPN transistor should turn on when the base current is 1/10th the collector current because hFE is used only when the transistor is an amplifier with plenty of collector voltage and here it is not an amplifier, it is a switch.

Comment: Thank you very much for yours detailed answers. You are right, the transistor is an NPN. I'm really sorry for the misanderstanding.

Comment: Where do the 1.28 V actually come from? The (100°C) irritates me. For the circuit to work, the source of the 1.28 V needs to be able to provide enough current to the base. Where does this voltage come from? I would also reduce the base resistor to a few hundred Ohms. I think the 100 Ohms in row with the buzzer is a problem too. The buzzer is really rated for only 2 V?

Comment: The circuit is meant to turn on a buzzer when the voltage on a thermistor reaches 1,28 V. It happens at 100 °C. It's for a fire alarm. I didn't't post the rest of the circuit because I thought it was not relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming an NTC thermistor in an unbuffered resistor divider, the circuit is more like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXr9M9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Using a PTC thermistor would swap the variable resistor and \$R_1\$.)

The above circuit would cause the voltage at the divider node to climb as the temperature increased.

Looking at a [Murata datasheet](https://www.murata.com/%7E/media/webrenewal/support/library/catalog/products/thermistor/ntc/r44e.ashx):

[image]

The resistance at \$100^\circ\:\text{C}\$ (circled in blue) is about \$\frac1{10}\text{th}\$ of its nominal value at room temperature (circled in green.)

At nominal temperature, the NTC thermistors from Murata come in three ranges:

\$\quad\quad\quad\$[image]

If the thermistor is a common \$10\:\text{k}\Omega\$ variety then its resistance at \$100^\circ\:\text{C}\$ will be about \$1\:\text{k}\Omega\$ at the point where the buzzer should turn on. Assuming that \$+5\:\text{V}\$ also supplies the thermistor+resistor divider, I'd guess \$R_1=2.7\:\text{k}\Omega\$. This suggests a Thevenin impedance at the trigger point of about \$700\:\Omega\$.

Even if \$R_2=0\:\Omega\$, the design isn't well-managed. Setting \$\beta=10\$ and therefore \$I_{_\text{B}}=3\:\text{mA}\$ means that the managed plan is for a \$2.1\:\text{V}\$ drop across the thevenin resistance relative to its unloaded value. And that just won't work.

Worse, there's no designed hysteresis. Instead, a gradually increasing collector current occurs as the thermistor resistance gradually changes with temperature.

Is an unbuffered resistor divider arrangement being used?

Answer (score 0):

I think I spotted **my mistakes** and I want to share them with you.

1. The transistor is actually a BJT NPN
2. I didn't know that "Ib is 1/10th the collector current because hFE is used only when the transistor is an amplifier with plenty of collector voltage and here it is not an amplifier, it is a switch" so I used the wrong plot from the datasheet.
3. Taking Ib= Ic/10 allows the transistor to be working in saturation (switch fully on). That's because the current base is higher than the one you would obtain referring to the plot for hfe on the datasheet.
   While working in saturation, the Vce is smaller for the same Ib. That entails less power dissipation
4. The correct circut should be the one attached below:

[image]

5. I think the purpose of this plot is giving you the voltage drop between base and emittor dependign on Ic, isn't it?

[image]

Comment: You did not notice that the graph of base-emitter voltage is when it is an amplifier with 1V collector to emitter.  The graph for SATURATED base-emitter ON voltage has a voltage a little higher than when it is a saturated switch because the base-collector is forward biased and drawing a little current.

Comment: The thermistor and circuit are not a switch.  The circuit will audibly make a noise in when the temperature is a normal room temperature and get louder as the temperature rises.